How to conditionally update a column in a Polars DataFrame with values from a list in Python?
I am trying to update specific rows in a python-polars DataFrame where two columns ("Season" and "Wk") meet certain conditions, using values from a list or Series that should align with the filtered rows. In pandas, I would use .loc[] to do this, but I haven't found a way to achieve the same result with Polars.
import polars as pl

# Sample DataFrame
df = pl.DataFrame({
    "Season": [2024, 2024, 2024, 2024],
    "Wk": [28, 28, 29, 29],
    "position": [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

# List of new values for the filtered rows
new_positions = [10, 20]  # Example values aligned with the filtered rows

# Condition to update only where Season is 2024 and Wk is 29
df = df.with_columns(
    # Expected update logic here
)

I've tried approaches with when().then() and zip_with(), but they either don't accept lists/Series directly or don't align the new values correctly with the filtered rows. Is there a recommended way to update a column conditionally in python-polars with values from a list or Series in the same order as the filter?

I'm assuming the result should be position: [1, 2, 10, 20]? If you could show the expected output dataframe too, that would be helpful.

You could generate the indices with when/then and .cum_sum()
df.with_columns(
   idx = pl.when(Season=2024, Wk=29).then(1).cum_sum() - 1
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬─────┬──────────┬──────┐
│ Season ┆ Wk  ┆ position ┆ idx  │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      ┆ ---  │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64      ┆ i32  │
╞════════╪═════╪══════════╪══════╡
│ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 1        ┆ null │
│ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 2        ┆ null │
│ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 3        ┆ 0    │
│ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 4        ┆ 1    │
└────────┴─────┴──────────┴──────┘

Which you can .get() and then .fill_null() the remaining original values.
df.with_columns(
   pl.lit(pl.Series(new_positions))
     .get(pl.when(Season=2024, Wk=29).then(1).cum_sum() - 1)
     .fill_null(pl.col.position)
     .alias("position")
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ Season ┆ Wk  ┆ position │
│ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64      │
╞════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 1        │
│ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 2        │
│ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 10       │
│ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 20       │
└────────┴─────┴──────────┘

Or perhaps .replace_strict()
df.with_columns(
   (pl.when(Season=2024, Wk=29).then(1).cum_sum() - 1)
      .replace_strict(dict(enumerate(new_positions)), default=pl.col.position)
      .alias("position")
)


In-place update
The following works as in-place update in polars.
df[[2, 3], "position"] = new_positions

Instead of a list of indices, a dataframe with single integer column may also be passed. Especially, we can do the following.
idx = df.select(
    pl.int_range(pl.len()).filter(pl.col("Season") == 2024, pl.col("Wk") == 29)
)

df[idx, "position"] = new_positions


pl.DataFrame.update
An alternative approach could look as follows.

Add an index to df using pl.DataFrame.with_row_index.
Create a new (temporary) dataframe, which only contains the rows of interest. Here, the position column can be overwritten as a whole with the new values.
Use pl.DataFrame.update to update only the values of interest in df with those in the temporary dataframe.

(
    df
    .with_row_index()
    .update(
        other=(
            df
            .with_row_index()
            .filter(
                pl.col("Season") == 2024, pl.col("Wk") == 29
            ).with_columns(
                pl.Series("position", new_positions)
            )
        ),
        on="index"
    )
)

shape: (4, 4)
┌───────┬────────┬─────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ Season ┆ Wk  ┆ position │
│ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ --- ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ i64    ┆ i64 ┆ i64      │
╞═══════╪════════╪═════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 1        │
│ 1     ┆ 2024   ┆ 28  ┆ 2        │
│ 2     ┆ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 10       │
│ 3     ┆ 2024   ┆ 29  ┆ 20       │
└───────┴────────┴─────┴──────────┘

